# Horizontal Nested List View

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm currently working on the layout of an industrial app and have found it difficult to nest a horizontal ListView (or any ScrollView) inside a list of widgets without getting a `Failed assertion: '_initialButtons == kPrimaryButtons'` error that crashes the app. This only happens when the ListView is tapped with 2 fingers.

I've tried everything I could think of or find on the internet, including: NestedScrollView, ListView inside a SizedBox with constrained height, any combination of ScrollView widgets. I've also tried to clean the build files, and to setup a new project. All to no avail.

Here's a minimal, reproducible example and an error log: https://gist.github.com/RKasinCDRK/033ee9020cb2e7aecfa576c4f7d3f559

I expect the horizontal list to perform like any other scroll view without having any crashing behavior. This was found and tested on an iOS physical device.

Please help, I've spent way too long trying to figure out something so simple ...

Comment: Hi. Could you give us the code you are working on please ?

Comment: The gist contains code and error message. Hope that helps!